# When should I close cursor variable?

Tags: android, android-cursor, sqlite

I've find that I should close my cursor variable after every use. but the problem is when I'm trying to return cursor as the output of function. seems like It's not possible. look at my DbHelper that I've tried to close my cursor and database in my functions:

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "shareholders.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id integer,title text,description text,sDate text)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (id integer,name text)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        xLog.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public long insert(String table,ContentValues cv){
    SQLiteDatabase mydb =this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result=-1;
    try {
        result = mydb.insert(table,null, cv);
        }catch (Exception e) {
        xLog.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        mydb.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public Cursor selectAll(String table){
    SQLiteDatabase mydb =this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table;
    xLog.info(sql);
    Cursor result=null;
    try {
        result = mydb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        xLog.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        result.close();
        mydb.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public Cursor select(String table,String where){
    SQLiteDatabase mydb =this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table+" WHERE "+where;
    xLog.info(sql);

    Cursor result=null;
    try {
        result = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table+" WHERE "+where, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        xLog.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        result.close();
        mydb.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public long update(String table,ContentValues cv,String condition){
    SQLiteDatabase mydb =this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = -1;
    try {
        result = mydb.update(table, cv, condition, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        xLog.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        mydb.close();
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

}

How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You should close the `Cursor` after you've done using it. If you return the `Cursor` to caller, you're not yet done.

Some options:

- The caller which receives the `Cursor` becomes responsible of closing it.
- Your function copies the data from the `Cursor` to some other data structure, closes the cursor and returns the copied data.

Comment: So if I copy the cursor into another variable, finally I've one cursor still open yet! Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Don't copy the `Cursor` reference, that is assign to another variable, but loop through the cursor and copy each row of data to a data structure such as `ArrayList`.